# Cursor "fetch next from" - syntax error near from

Tags: sql, cursor, sybase, procedure

I want to create procedure that shows me products with 20% discount using cursor. After compiling code below I'm getting error message 
"Syntax error near "FROM" line 14. I'm using Sybase. Can anyone help me with this?
Here is my code:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE "ProduktyPoZnizce20procent2"( /* @parameter_name parameter_type [= default_value] [OUTPUT], ... */ )
AS
BEGIN
    declare @IDPR INTEGER 
    declare @typ  VARCHAR(30)
    declare @model varchar(30)
    declare @cena   float

DECLARE ProductCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT IDProduct from Product

Open ProductCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM ProductCursor
INTO @IDPR

while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN 
        select @typ = Product.product_type, @model=Product.name, @cena = Product.price * 0.8
        from Product
        where @IDPR = Product.IDProduct

        print(cast(@typ as nvarchar(30)) + ' ' + cast(@model as nvarchar(30)) + ' = ' + cast(@cena as varchar(10)))

        FETCH NEXT FROM ProductCursor INTO @IDPR

    END

close ProductCursor
DEALLOCATE CURSOR ProductCursor

END
```

Comment: Why would you use a cursor for this?  And, you have also written an infinite loop, but that would appear to be another matter.

Comment: "I'm using Sybase", while your question is tagged SQL Server.

Comment: Because I have to use cursor for something ( that is my project demand) and I didn't find something better. Why there is an infinite loop?

Comment: @Pawel - Which DBMS you are using `SQL SERVER` or `SYSBASE`

Comment: Strange I didnt tag this as a sql-server

Comment: @Pawel - why you need `cursor` when there is a simple way is present to do this

Comment: Because I need to show that I can implement cursor.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Why do you think there is an infinite loop?While(FETCH_STATUS = 0 ) checks whether there are more records to loop through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. There was 2 mistakes in my code: I wasn't going forward with my cursor. Proper syntax to send my cursor to the next line is

```
FETCH NEXT ProductCursor
INTO @IDPR
```

and it should be called at the before loop and in loop.

Next thing was to properly print result on the screen. Since

```
print(cast(@typ as nvarchar(30)) + ' ' + cast(@model as nvarchar(30)) + ' = ' + cast(@cena as varchar(10)))
```

does not give anything on the screen it must be replaced by

```
message (cast(@typ as nvarchar(30)) + ' ' + cast(@model as nvarchar(30)) + ' = ' + cast(@cena as varchar(10))) type status to client
```

Whole code now looks like this:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE "ProduktyPoZnizce20procent2"( /* @parameter_name parameter_type [= default_value] [OUTPUT], ... */ )
AS
BEGIN
    declare @IDPR INTEGER 
    declare @typ  VARCHAR(30)
    declare @model varchar(30)
    declare @cena   float

DECLARE ProductCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT IDProduct from Product

Open ProductCursor

FETCH NEXT ProductCursor
INTO @IDPR

while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN 
        select @typ = Product.product_type, @model=Product.name, @cena = Product.price * 0.8
        from Product
        where @IDPR = Product.IDProduct

        message(cast(@typ as nvarchar(30)) + ' ' + cast(@model as nvarchar(30)) + ' = ' + cast(@cena as varchar(10))) type status to client


    FETCH NEXT ProductCursor
    INTO @IDPR

    END

close ProductCursor
DEALLOCATE CURSOR ProductCursor

END
```

Answer (score 0):

All you are trying to do is

```
SELECT Cast(Product.product_type AS NVARCHAR(30))
       + " " + Cast(Product.NAME AS NVARCHAR(30))
       + " = "
       + Cast(Product.price * 0.8 AS VARCHAR(10))
FROM   Product
```

---

After some research about `cursor` in sysbase. I think

```
FETCH NEXT FROM ProductCursor INTO @IDPR
```

should be

```
fetch ProductCursor into @IDPR
```

---

```
DEALLOCATE ProductCursor
```

should be

```
deallocate cursor ProductCursor
```

---

For checking the records in loop `@@FETCH_STATUS` should be `@@sqlstatus`

```
/* now loop, processing all the rows
** @@sqlstatus = 0 means successful fetch
** @@sqlstatus = 1 means error on previous fetch
** @@sqlstatus = 2 means end of result set reached
*/

while (@@sqlstatus = 0)
Begin
..
End
```

Check here for more info on `CURSOR` in sysbase http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc20020_1251/html/databases/X61512.htm

Comment: Correct! But I need to use cursor and I came up with this. Maybe it's not a good example and I could come up with better idea. I'm learning curors  I just want to know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: It compiled successfully, but after 2 mins It didnt show my 20 products after discount.

Comment: @Pawel Do you have any `NULL's` in any of these columns  `product_type` or `NAME` or `price` ?

Comment: No. All columns are filled with data. ( not NULL).

Comment: @Pawel what do you meant by this *It didnt show my 20 products after discount.* ?

Comment: There were nothing after compilation. Just increasing execution time. Nothing has been printed on the screen.

Comment: @Pawel - Sorry.. am no expert in sysbase.. Just for your question I researched about sysbase and posted some fixes. Not sure what is wrong and why it is not printing. It should print because it is just a simple logic. Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your time @Prdp . I hope I'll find it soon. If I do, I'll let you know.